# Is there a good design pattern for this messaging class?

Tags: php, oop, class, design-patterns

Is there a good design pattern for this?

I want to create a messaging class.

The class will be passed:

- the type of message (eg. signup, signup confirmation, password reminder etc)
- the client's id

The class needs to then look up the client's messaging preferences in the db (whether they want communication by email, sms or both)

Then depending on the client's preference it will format the message for the medium (short version for sms, long form for email) and send it through our mail or sms provider's API.

Because the fact that we want to be able to change out email and sms providers if need be I wondered if the Command Pattern would be a good choice.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: This is likely a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll move it over there.  Is there some way to remove it from here?

Comment: Just close it. It doesn't hurt to leave it open, though, since someone might choose to answer it here. It's just that this kind of question is somewhat open-ended, and SO questions are expected to be for specific problems. The programmers site is more geared towards "discussion-style" questions...

Comment: Look at the strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a pattern for this. It sounds more like just simple inheritance with an abstract method for the actual message sending.

Consider dividing the tasks better. Perhaps make it the responsibility of the user ID to look up the preferences, or just code a third class for it.

If you want to use a design pattern, then Builder might apply to constructing the actual messages. This depends on whether you need different formatting for the different message delivery methods.